# Form.non_fields_errors()

Tags: django

I know how to display a 'bound' message on a form with

```
def clean_ref1_fullname(self):
    value = self.form.cleaned_data.get('ref1_fullname', '').title()
    if value in (None, ''):
        raise ValidationError(
            _('"Reference 1 - Fullname" is required')
        )
    return value

def clean_ref1_fullname(self):
    value = self.form.cleaned_data.get('ref1_fullname', '').title()
    if value in (None, ''):
        raise ValidationError(
            _('"Reference 1 - Fullname" is required')
        )
    return value
```

It will display a message on a specific field. I would like to display a global message. How could I do that? Assume this form is simply `ExampleForm()`.

Comment: If the validation is not bound to a specific field you should override the `clean` method and raise `ValidationError` there. If you want to display the validation errors as global errors, you can just move the logic form the `clean_fieldname` methods into the `clean` method, remove the `returns` and return the whole `cleaned_data` dictionary in the end.

Comment: Could you display a full answer with an example with what you explained to me? What do you mean by override the `clean` method? Sorry, I do not have a lot of experience with django.

Comment: @PauloScardine Sorry, I think I need an example of what you told me.

Comment: I think you really need to test your app a bit before asking here, because unless you declare the form field with `required=False` or the model with `blank=True, null=True` the validation in your code sample will be default. That said, I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your validation to the `clean` method if you don't want it to be attached to a particular field.

```
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    ref1_fullname = forms.CharField(required=False)

    def clean(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if not cd['ref1_fullname']:
            raise ValidationError(_('"Reference 1 - Fullname" is required'))
        return cd
```

Note that unless you mark the field as not required, Django will do that for you. If it is a `ModelForm` and the model field lacks a `null=True` and/or `blank=True` the field will not allow empty values.